# VB.NET - How to detect javascript:launch and prevent it from opening a web browser?

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net, internet-explorer

With preparing for the IE11 desktop program's removal from Windows, I wanted to create a program that used the WebBrowser WinForm element in VB.NET as it used the IE engine to allow people to continue accessing their network camera WebUI. Most of it works with minimal code but if a user clicks on a link that has javascript:launch on it, it will attempt to open that in iexplore but that will fail and redirect to Edge which is something I don't want as that can prevent people from installing required addons to their network camera.

So what I want to do is to intersect that and open it in my own form rather than the IE desktop program so something like:
When user clicks on a javascript:launch it should:
Take the IP of the current camera view (I've already got this stored in a variable, IP) and combine it with the file it's trying to open with the launch. Then prevent IE or Edge from opening and spawn its own form and navigate to the document within the program so something like this

```
if webbrowser navigate includes javascript:launch
cancel opening IE/Edge
form2.show()
form2.webbrowser.navigate(JavaScriptLaunch URL)
```

I have no idea how to write the first two parts so that's where I need some help. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What the "javascript:launch" link, can you post the related code about it? 

From your description, after using the WebBrowser control display the web page, you need to retrieve all the hyperlinks, then check whether the hyperlink contains `javascript:launch` or not. If that is the case, you could consider doing this action in the WebBrowser's DocumentCompleted event, code [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clAIn.png).

Comment: Sorry about the delay, but I want to detect JS code like this: <a href="#" onclick="javascript:launch('/help/liveview_h.shtml?cntrlQue='); return false;" class="linkInActive" id="view_HelpTxt">Help</a> and prevent it from opening IE but instead opening it in my own web view in my WinForm program

Comment: Are you using the WebBrowser control in your WinForm application? If that is the case, in the WebBrowser's DocumentCompleted event, you could use the `Document.GetElementsByTagName` method to find all `<a>` tag, then use `GetAttribute()` method to get the `onclick` attribute and check whether it is start with 'javascript:launch', then open it in your own web view.